Spring Cloud Dataflow 2.11.4 on GKE 1.29.6: Server POD crashing
I am hosting SCDF on GKE by following below documentation -
https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/kubectl/
PODS for all components are up and running but getting below error with SCDF server POD:
Description:
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.fabric8' to io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config:
Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from
The POD is Crashing on start. Is it a incompatibility issues of K8 and SCDF versions?
I tried different versions of SCDF docker images.

I would suggest following the Carvel deployment described here https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/carvel/
